Ubuntu 24.04 - not restarting (need to power off and press power button)
I have strange problem that I don't know even how to debug to find rootcause of it.
Problem is trivial - when I do sudo reboot. The screen fall black etc but its not restarting at all. I need to hold power button for some time and press it one more time and it will boot normally. So first question is how can I debug this / find any logs that will show what is going on and what process is hanging ?
